# In skaffold/v2alpha3, i am getting error of "property manifests is not allowed"

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, skaffold

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests: 
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: fifapes123/auth
      context: auth
      docker: 
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync: 
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

I am getting error on line number 5?I am using the skaffold/v2alpha3 in which manifests under kubectl is allowed then why i am getting "property manifests is not allowed"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v3
kind: Config
build:
 artifacts:
  - image: fifapes123/auth
    context: auth
    sync:
     manual:
     - src: src/**/*.ts
       dest: .
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
local:
 push: false
manifests:
 rawYaml:
 - ./infra/k8s/*
deploy:
 kubectl: {}
```

Try the above YAML config. You should [update](https://skaffold.dev/docs/upgrading/) your `skaffold.yaml` to the latest apiVersion (apiVersion: v3alpha1). This can be easily done by `skaffold fix` command